# ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid) ValueError: External ID not found in the system: gen_doc.report_cahier_des_charges

Tags: python, odoo

I'm facing an error when I go in my module to a specific user for example and go to print something.

There is my error of odoo:

raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: gen_doc.report_cahier_des_charges

To explain a little bit more, I'm trying to get the information from the basic module Employees of Odoo and in a custom module to do a report with those information of Employees.

I'm new in Odoo so i hope that I gave your enough information.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check if the XML file where you defined the `gen_doc.report_cahier_des_charges` report is loaded

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer. I think that yes it's loaded because I have my button with "print" at the top and when I click on it, it appears with the name " cahier des charges " but when i click on it i'm getting the error upper. When i'm reloading my custom module i have no error.

Answer (score 0):

The error states what the issue is.

1. Either the xml id used (in your case "report_cahier_des_charges")is not defined anywhere in the module which is causing the error. So define this xml id.
2. Or you defined the xml id alright, but it is defined below the report calling it. In this case, just move the record whose id is "report_cahier_des_charges" above the report calling it. Probably right after/below the odoo or data tags, just to be safe.

I hope this helps :)